# Pass a variable to user control to determine display

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, code-behind

Apologies if this is something really simple.

I've found various C# examples here, but I can't seem to get a VB version working.

I want to be able to pass a simple variable into a User Control to determine whether it shows a certain section of data.

It's basically a Customer Data form, and in some circumstances I need to show a line with the customers account number and sort code, and in some I don't, so my user control:

```
<controls:customerForm ID='customerForm' showBankDetails="no" runat='server' />
```

But I can't work out what to do with the showBankDetails variable in Code Behind to stop it from rendering that section, or simply hide it with a CSS snippet.

How do I access that variable in the code behind using VB.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I'd have optional stuff in a asp:panel on the page in the right spot, and in the page load or where ever, do something like:

```
me.OptionalStuffPanel.Visible = me.ShowBankDetails
```

`ShowBankDetails` would need to be defined as a public property of the page class:

```
private _ShowBankDetails as boolean
Public Property ShowBankDetails() As boolean
    Get
        Return _ShowBankDetails
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As boolean)
        _ShowBankDetails = value
    End Set
End Property
```

If you want the property to appear in the property grid here is an article to show you how!

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/using_propertygrid.aspx

Comment: Brilliant! It's so simple when you know how! Thanks.

Comment: If you want it to show up on the property page there is some attributes you need to add to the property... I forget which ones exactly. Don't worry if the property is not listed in properties or intellisense until those attributes are added. Hmmm which ones are they....

Comment: Here we go - Edited with link!